# icon_emoji is not working with slack client

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

I made a java application to send message to slack.

**1. I use `slack-api-client` libary.**

```
// build.gradle
implementation "com.slack.api:slack-api-client:1.9.0"
```

**2. I use bot token.**
And bot has `chat:write`, `chat:write.public`, `chat:write.customize` permissions.

```java
Slack slack = Slack.getInstance();
AsyncMethodsClient client = slack.methodsAsync("xoxb-xxxxx");
```

**3. I set the message as follows.**

```json
{
  "channel": "channel_name",
  "username": "slack-bot",
  "icon_emoji": ":bell:",
  "text": "hi"
}
```

**4. I use `chat.postMessage` method.**

```java
ChatPostMessageResponse response = client.chatPostMessage(message);
```

But I got a message with default app's image as user icon instead of `:bell:` emoji.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the latest version of the Java SDK is 1.10.0 Try upgrading maybe that'll make a difference?